# Notation for a turn with a half step

Tags: piano, notation, ornaments

From what I've read, turns only seem to use the notes in the key, so if I'm in C Major, what would be the notation for a turn with G-A-G-F#-G ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A little sharp below the turn sign:

[image: Turn with sharp.]

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be better to just write out exactly what you want instead of using a turn. The purpose of ornaments is to quickly notate common patterns to "ornament" the melody. Deviating from the standard can lead to confusion especially if the alteration isn't very well known. [This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornament_(music)#Turn) shows how a turn would be notated without actually using the turn notation.

Comment: Depending on the style it might not be desirable to be too specific about how the ornament is laid out. Indeed, in Irish folk tunes and the like you may find a turn written, and some players will make a note sharp, some will use the natural scale, and some will play entirely different notes... all ad-lib!